# product of two riemann integrable is riemann integrable

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

first show you only need to consider squares of functions as 
f.g = 1/4 [(f+g)sqr - (f-g)sqr].
show then that you only need to consider only positive valued functions becuase f(x).g(x)=|f(x)|sqr.
then , if 0 <=f(x) <= M on [a,b] show that f sqr(x) - f sqr(y) <= 2M (f(x)-f(y)).

does anyone know how i would answer this ??

Comment: If this is a homework problem, then -- as stated in the FAQ http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot -- your question would be better suited to one of the sites mentioned there.

Comment: This question has been reasked on MSE, so could be closed here without loss.

Answer (score 2):

It follows from Lebesgue's characterization of Riemann
integrable functions as bounded functions continuous outside
a set of Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but is there a simpler approach because i am only a second year student and we have not covered Lebesgue's characterization of Riemann integrable functions at all.

Comment: So this was a **homework question**?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ and $g$ are Riemann integrable over the interval $[a,b]$ then there is an $M$ such that $|f|$ and $|g|$ are both $\le M$ on $[a,b]$. The Riemann integrability of $f g$ then immediately follows from the inequality
$$|f(x)g(x)-f(x')g(x')|\le |f(x)-f(x')||g(x)|+|f(x')||g(x)-g(x')|$$ $$\le
M(|f(x)-f(x')| +|g(x)-g(x')|) $$
for all $x, x'\in [a,b]$.